# model.parameters() not updating in Linear Regression with Pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I'm a newbie in Deep Learning with Pytorch. I am using the Housing Prices dataset from Kaggle here. I tried sampling with first 50 rows. But the model.parameters() is not updating as I perform the training. Can anyone help?

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F

inputs = np.array(label_X_train[:50])
targets = np.array(train_y[:50])

# Tensors
inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)
targets = torch.from_numpy(targets)
targets = targets.view(-1, 1)
train_ds = TensorDataset(inputs, targets)
batch_size = 5
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = nn.Linear(10, 1)
# Define Loss func
loss_fn = F.mse_loss
# Optimizer
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-5)


num_epochs = 100
model.train()         
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Train with batches of data
    for xb, yb in train_dl:

        # 1. Generate predictions
        pred = model(xb.float())

        # 2. Calculate loss
        loss = loss_fn(pred, yb.float())
    
        # 3. Compute gradients
        loss.backward()

        # 4. Update parameters using gradients
        opt.step()

        # 5. Reset the gradients to zero
        opt.zero_grad()
     
    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch +
                                                   1, num_epochs, 
                                                   loss.item()))
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working, at least it's modifying the weights of the model. I tried with `lr=0.1` and they change. Can you further explain what you mean by `model.parameters()` don't change ?

Comment: Thanks but the weights aren't changing for me at a low learning rate. And at `lr=0.1` it gives me this error:`RuntimeError: Function 'AddmmBackward' returned nan values in its 2th output.`

Comment: I tried normalizing the dataset and it does not give me the error but the weights are still not updating:`print(w==w_new): tensor([[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]])`

Comment: How do you define `w` and `w_new` ? They are not in your posted code. I simply printed `list(model.parameters())` after `opt.zero_grad()` and the weights seem to be changing (with random inputs) !

Comment: `w = model.weight.data` before training and `w_new = model.weight.data` after training but both give the same results. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Found the problem then, look at the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight does update, but you weren't capturing it correctly. `model.weight.data` is a torch tensor, but the name of the variable is just a reference, so setting `w = model.weight.data` does not create a copy but another reference to the object. Hence changing `model.weight.data` would change `w` too.

So by setting `w = model.weight.data` and `w_new = model.weight data` in different part of the loops means you're assigning two reference to the same object making their value equal at all time.

In order to assess that the model weight are changing, either `print(model.weight.data)` before and after the loop (since you got one linear layer of 10 parameters it's still okay to do that) or simply set `w = model.weight.data.clone()`. In that case your output will be:

```
tensor([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Here's an example that shows you that your weights are changing:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F

inputs = np.random.rand(50, 10)
targets = np.random.randint(0, 2, 50)

# Tensors
inputs = torch.from_numpy(inputs)
targets = torch.from_numpy(targets)
targets = targets.view(-1, 1)
train_ds = TensorDataset(inputs, targets.squeeze())
batch_size = 5
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = nn.Linear(10, 1)
# Define Loss func
loss_fn = F.mse_loss
# Optimizer
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 1e-1)


num_epochs = 100
model.train()
w = model.weight.data.clone()         
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Train with batches of data
    for xb, yb in train_dl:

        # 1. Generate predictions
        pred = model(xb.float())

        # 2. Calculate loss
        loss = loss_fn(pred, yb.float())
    
        # 3. Compute gradients
        loss.backward()

        # 4. Update parameters using gradients
        opt.step()

        # 5. Reset the gradients to zero
        opt.zero_grad()

    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch +
                                                   1, num_epochs, 
                                                   loss.item()))
print(w == model.weight.data)
```

Comment: But I have 1 more problem. The loss is not reducing. It shows a very erratic pattern. This is the result on training:                       `Epoch [10/100], Loss: 62795599872.0000
Epoch [20/100], Loss: 271929212928.0000
Epoch [30/100], Loss: 49614417920.0000
Epoch [40/100], Loss: 45698277376.0000
Epoch [50/100], Loss: 306665979904.0000
Epoch [60/100], Loss: 137889562624.0000
Epoch [70/100], Loss: 296052654080.0000
Epoch [80/100], Loss: 178698993664.0000
Epoch [90/100], Loss: 89476120576.0000
Epoch [100/100], Loss: 85041545216.0000`

Comment: That can be due to many reasons, but a loss this big probably means that your learning rate is too high, or your data is not normalized. You should probably open a different thread or look if there aren't more detailed answer on SO.