# Weights not updating on my neural net (Pytorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm completely new to neural nets, so I tried to roughly follow some tutorials to create a neural net that can just distinguish if a given binary picture contains a white circle or if it is all black. So, I generated 1000 arrays of size 10000 representing a 100x100 picture with half of them containing a white circle somewhere. The generation of my dataset looks like this:

```
for i in range(1000):
   image = [0] * (IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE)

   if random() < 0.5:
      dataset.append([image, [[0]]])

   else:
      #inserts circle in image
      #...

      dataset.append([image, [[1]]])

np.random.shuffle(dataset)
np.save("testdataset.npy", dataset)
```

The double list around the classifications is because the net seemed to give that format as an output, so I matched that.

Now since I don't really have any precise idea of how pytorch works, I don't really now which parts of the code are relevant for solving my problem and which aren't. Therefore, I gave the code for the net and the training down below and really hope that someone can explain to me where I went wrong. I'm sorry if it's too much code. The code runs without errors, but if I print the parameters before and after training they didn't change in any way and the net will always just return a 0 for every image/array.

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 100
EPOCHS = 3
BATCH_SIZE = 50
VAL_PCT = 0.1

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, 1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim = 1)
    
net = Net()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
dataset = np.load("testdataset.npy", allow_pickle = True)

X = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in dataset]).view(-1, 10000)
y = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in dataset])

val_size = int(len(X) * VAL_PCT)

train_X = X[:-val_size]
train_y = y[:-val_size]

test_X = X[-val_size:]
test_y = y[-val_size:]

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_X = train_X[i:i + BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 10000)
        batch_y = train_y[i:i + BATCH_SIZE]

        net.zero_grad()

        outputs = net(batch_X)
        loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: I answered a question similar to this one in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775976/model-parameters-not-updating-in-linear-regression-with-pytorch/62849287#62849287 if that doesn't help could you provide the code where you also test out if the weights change ?

Comment: If  I see it correctly, your problem is that your network has only one output weight, but you then apply the softmax function. softmax function converts a set of numbers into something like probabilities summing to 1. Hence, your output will be independent of your input. You could just use 2 outputs in your last layer. I think the `dim` in the softmax has to be 2, the way you coded it

Comment: @Youyoun I read your other answer now and changed my way of comparing so the weights do indeed change and I just checked wrong - the net still returned 0 on every input though.

Comment: @McLawrence My last layer now returns 2 outputs, however, when I try testing the net with ``output = net(test_X[0].view(-1, 1, 10000))`` the results are always negative, like ``tensor([[[-0.9464, -0.4913]]])``, when in fact it should be ``tensor([[0., 1.]])``.

Comment: Side note, I would recommend you taking a look at those tutorials: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/deep_learning_60min_blitz.html . They explain quite well how pytorch works and some basic notions of machine learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `net.zero_grad()` I would recommend using `optimizer.zero_grad()` as it's more common and de facto standard. Your training loop should be:

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    for i in range(0, len(train_X), BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_X = train_X[i:i + BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 10000)
        batch_y = train_y[i:i + BATCH_SIZE]

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = net(batch_X)
        loss = loss_function(outputs, batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I would recommend you reading a bit about different loss functions. It seems you have a classification problem, for that you should use the logits (binary classification) or cross entropy (multi class) loss. I would make the following changes to the network and loss function:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, 1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return x
    
loss_function = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

Check the documentation before using it: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bcewithlogitsloss

Good luck!

Comment: `If you do net.zero_grad() you do not update the hooks of the optimizer. It should fix your training.`

Where did you get this information? Looking at [`torch.nn.Module`'s `zero_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.zero_grad) and [`torch.optim.Optimizer`'s `zero_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad) source codes both are equivalent for single parameter group (as is the case here). See also [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-the-difference-between-optimizer-zero-grad-vs-nn-module-zero-grad/59233).

Comment: @SzymonMaszke, you are right. I changed the answer to reflect it. Thank you for noting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, It is not ideal to use Neural networks for address this kind of problems. Neural Networks train on highly non-linear data. For this example, You can use average intensities of image to find out a white pixel is present or not
2. However, A classic logistic regression problem outputs a value from 0 to 1 or probabilities
3. Softmax function is used when you have multiple classes and convert all the sum of classes equal to 1
4. log_softmax implementation: log( exp(x_i) / exp(x).sum() ). Here, your output layer consists of only 1 neuron. `outputs = net(batch_X)` is always 1.